# Wine not working in Ubuntu 17.04

Tags: wine

I am not able to run Sony Password Protection Manager exe file to unlock hidden partition in external hard drive on Ubuntu 17.04 machine.

```
err:shell:SHGetFileInfoW pidl is null!
```

No clue about error.
Wine version - wine-1.8.7 (Ubuntu 1.8.7-1ubuntu1)

Please need help.

With Regards,
Nirav Pradhan

Comment: Does it ever worked in previous releases? Doubtfully, therefore a misleading  title right there. Proprietary software with low level hardware access hardly if ever works with Wine or emulators. You need to run the software natively in Windows.

Comment: Thanks @CelticWarrior for the response. I will try running on Windows VM & see if it works.